# Count Rows in CSV files and export results to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am trying count the rows containing values in a bunch of CSV in a folder. I managed to get the code to count it but I can't seem to find a way to export the results to a CSV. All I got is a blank CSV.

What am I missing here?

```
$FOLDER_ROOT = "C:\Test\2019"
$OUTPUT_CSV = "C:\Test\2019\Count.csv"

Get-ChildItem $FOLDER_ROOT -re -in "*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $filestats = Get-Content $_.Fullname | Measure-Object -Line
    $linesInFile = $filestats.Lines - 1
    Write-Host "$_,$linesInFile"
} | Export-Csv -Path $OUTPUT_CSV -NoType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- Use `Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv'` instead of `Get-ChildItem -Include '*.csv'`. The former is faster than the latter.
- `Write-Host` most likely causes the output to go directly to the host console. I've been told that this was changed in recent versions (so that host output goes to the new information stream), but for versions at least prior to v5 it's still a reality.
- `Export-Csv` expects object input, since it outputs the properties of the objects as the fields of the CSV (taking the column titles from the property names of the first object). Feeding it strings (`"$_,$linesInFile"`) will result in a CSV that contains only a column "Length", since that is the only property of the string objects.

Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for creating a CSV with the filename and line count of the input files:

```
Get-ChildItem $FOLDER_ROOT -Recurse -Filter '*.csv' |
    Select-Object Name, @{n='LineCount';e={(Get-Content $_.Fullname | Measure-Object -Line).Lines - 1}} |
    Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host` writes only to the host! Most probably you see the output into the PowerShell Console? 
Use `Write-Output`, which could be piped to Export-CSV.

Comment: You don't need `Write-Host` nor `Write-Output` to pipe data to `Export-CSV`.